# Convert a list containing 10 elemnts into three dimentional array

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I have a list with 10 elements with these shapes `[(1, 13),(2, 13),(2, 13),(13, 13),(4, 13),(5, 13),(5, 13),(6, 13),(2, 13),(8, 13)]`. Every element in a list is a two dimensional for example first element of list is an `array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.33, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.67, 0.  , 0.  ]])`

I want to convert this list into three dimensional array with `dimensions(10,?,13)` but the problem is second dimension is not a fixed number and it is changed for every case. Is there any way to do this?

I have to feed this three dimensional input into my Keras model.

Comment: If it depends on the shape, for example, you could make a dict with its keys as tuples mapping between shapes and the second dimensions. Further, I'd say it depends heavily on how easily you implement the "case" you refer to as code. Does each case depend on the shape? Can the second dimension be generated solely using the shape as input (for example a dict of type `Dict[tuple, Callable]`)?

Comment: Try to clarify what you need for that 2nd dimension a bit more, the answer really depends on it. If you need the 3d array to contain each 2d array once with some space left over, then that 2nd dimension just needs to be 13. If you need to repeat each 2d array to fill the 3d array with no space left over, then that 2nd dimension needs to be 1560.

Comment: My list is actually list of  sentences and within the list are some values for each word so each word is 1x13. If a sentence is 5 words so this will be of shape 5x13. so  it all depends and vary with the number of words within each sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

padding is all you need

recreate your data:

```
X = []
for _ in range(10):
    i = np.random.randint(15)
    x = np.random.uniform(0,1, (i,13))
    X.append(x)
```

use padding:

```
max_dim = 20

X_pad = []
for x in X:
    X_pad.append(np.pad(x, ((max_dim-len(x),0),(0,0)), mode='constant')) # pre padding
    # X_pad.append(np.pad(x, ((0,max_dim-len(x)),(0,0)), mode='constant')) # post padding
    
X_pad = np.stack(X_pad)
X_pad.shape # (10, max_dim, 13)
```

Comment: the max length for second dimension is 107. so if  length of x is one then it will pad 106 elements with zeros. Is it necessary to pad and make them of same size?

Comment: correct. yes, it's necessary to pad ALL and make ALL of the same size. you need to set max_dim which is >= than the max len of your array. for example, if 107 is the max length, set max_dim with an integer >= 107. don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: and what I have to make this padding as post and not pre padding?

Comment: in general is 'pre' but this not a critical choice, you can try both. (in my edit I made the diversification)